# Ajax - call in Wordpress fired twice... I looked for the othr answers but didn't find a solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hey I tried so manythings and didin't found yet a solution. I simplified my solution as much I could. Toggle on a 'td' (html element) so it could change from class. (actualy that's a kick-off to do more stuff)

I put the two 'console.log' lines for a kind of debug in the inspector, you will see it fires twices.

If I put the enque-line in comment it fires once but i get a nasty fault-message.

Hopefully somebody can help me,
Thanks in advance

```js
<script>
/* functions.js */
jQuery('td').click(function () {
     if (jQuery(this).hasClass('not_active')) {

            jQuery(this).removeClass('not_active').addClass('active');
            toggle=1;
            console.log('toggle ----> '+ toggle);
            
        }
        else {
               jQuery(this).removeClass('active').addClass('not_active');
               toggle=0;
               console.log('toggle ----> '+ toggle);
        }

         jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType:'json',
                data: { action: 'save_Settings',
                        App_active: toggle
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(WorkingHoursAction.success);
                }
        });
});

</script>
```

```css
/* style.css */
.Working{
    color:white;
    background-color: green;
}
.NotWorking{
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">#</th>
              <th>Actie</th>
          </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody id="Confirmed">
          <tr>
              <?php for($rw=0;$rw<7;$rw++){
                           
                          ?><td class="text-center day-hour notWorking" ><?php echo $rw; ?></td><?php
                    }
               ?>
                                     
        </tr>
          </tbody>
    
</table>


<?php

function OIC_enqueue(){ 
   wp_enqueue_script('OCI_jquery', plugins_url('js/functions.js',__FILE__),array('jquery'),'1',true);
   wp_enqueue_style('OCI_style',plugins_url('css/style.css',__FILE__));
    
   wp_enqueue_script('OCI_ChangeToggle',plugins_url('js/functions.js',__FILE__),
               array('jquery'),'1',true);
   wp_localize_script('OCI_ChangeToggle','ToggleAction',array(
              'security'   => wp_create_nonce('ChangeWhours'),
              'success'   => 'ChangeWorkinghours OK'));
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','OIC_enqueue');

function ToggleAction(){
    
        global $wpdb;

        $tblName = 'Settings';
        $active=stripslashes_deep($_POST['App_active']);

           $Data = array( 'App_active'        => $active );

            $condition = array( 'id'=> 1);
            
            $wpdb->update( 'WorkingTimes',  $WorkingHoursData, $condition, array('%s',  '%d', '%d' ), array( '%s','%d' ) );
            exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_save_Settings','ToggleAction');

?>
```

Comment: have you fixed the issue? please share the code it would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code it seems like you added `js/functions.js` two times.

Can you please check.

Comment: Yes once to trigger the 'td'.click and another tie to couple the ajax to the function.